# A Complete Video App source code for Samsung Smart TV App

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, samsung-smart-tv

I want to implement vod and live streaming, Tv series app for samsung smart tv.
Where I can get a sample complete video app source code for samsung smart tv app.

like sample application..

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the official documentation on http://www.samsungdforum.com and http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide.

More relevant stuff here:

- [Creating a Video Application](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/index.html?Foldername=tut00055&Filename=index.html)
- [Guideline for Smooth Streaming Application Developers](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/index.html?Foldername=art00112&Filename=index.html)
- [Creating a Video Application With HAS (HTTP Adaptive Streaming)](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/index.html?Foldername=tut00062&Filename=index.html)

You can find a sample app there (check the first bullet link), here's the direct link:
http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/_downloads/tut00055_tutorial_video_source_v1_31.zip

Enjoy ^^

Comment: Thanks Rui, 
your reply helps me a lot.

Comment: May i know why the source code loads the playlist correctly on simulator but on real device(D series) it is empty ? should any .js library be updated to new version ? I would appreciate if you help me fix this issue.Thanks